# Почему в console выводится Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined

Tags: javascript

```js
var per = {};
per.age = 25;
var key = 'age';

console.log(per[key]) // будет правильно 

var person = {};
person.age = 25;
var key = age;

console.log(person[key]) // будет ошибка
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
var key = age;
```

Переменная `age` не объявлена.

Comment: я знаю что age нужно завернуть в строку и будет правильно, но почему ? как ВЫ выше написали без завертывания в строку age она равна undefined правильно ?

Comment: @xes Нет. Она не равна `undefined`. Ее вообще нет. В этом и состоит ошибка. "Завернуть в строку" - хм, никакого "завертывания" здесь нет.

Comment: чтобы избежать ошибки надо в моем примере var key = age; age  сделать так 'age' (завернуть строку) тогда alert(person[age])  выведет 25

Comment: @xes Это понятно - вместо необъявленной переменной `age` будет строковое значение `"age"`.

Comment: изменил код посмотрите плиз

Comment: @xes Это понятно - вместо необъявленной переменной `age` будет строковое значение `"age"`, но они не имеют отношения друг к другу.

Comment: почему тогда не выводит 'age'  а выводит 25 ?

Comment: @xes Потому что у объекта, на который указывает переменная `per`, есть свойство `age`, и оно имеет значение `25`.

Comment: получается когда мы присваиваем название свойства(ключом)  мы фактически работам самим свойством ?

Comment: @xes Наверное - да, если Вас правильно понял ).

Comment: понятно брооооооооооооооооооо

Comment: а почему 'age'   именно заворачивают в строку ? можно ведь было и сделать и без строки ? почему именно строка которая содержит в себе значение 25 ?

Comment: @xes потому что `age` - это *название* свойства

Comment: @ Igor теперь понятно тут написано https://learn.javascript.ru/object Названия свойств можно перечислять как в кавычках, так и без, если они удовлетворяют ограничениям для имён переменных.